# Lagrange's four-square theorem and a task about finding a perfect square

Tags: number-theory

> *Find all integers $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^n+15=x^2$.*

This is a problem from the IMO, held in South Africa in 2009.

Do I need the [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) to solve the problem, because in the task it was written that **$x$ can be represented as the sum of four integer squares.**

How could this help me to solve the problem?

Comment: You do not need this, there are other possibilities. Search for [Ramanujan-Nagell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation) $x^2-D=2^n$.

Answer (score 2):

$n=0$ is a solution but there are no solutions with $n>0$.

First remark that if $n$ is odd then $$2^{2k+1}+15\equiv -1\pmod 3$$ and is therefore not a square.

Now assume that $n=2k$ is even.  But then $2^n$ is clearly a square so we are looking for two squares with $a^2-15=b^2$.    Since $(k+1)^2-k^2=2k+1$ we see that $2^n$ would have to be very small ($(1^2,4^2)$ and $(7^2,8^2)$ are the only examples of two squares a distance $15$ apart) so a quick search rules out all the possibilities with $n>0$.

As an alternative approach (to avoid the search) note that:  $$a^2-b^2=15\implies (a+b)(a-b)=15$$  so  $(a+b,a-b)=(15,1)\; \text {or} \;(5,3)$ and we get the same two solutions as before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to notice that if $n\ge3$ then $2^n+15\equiv7\bmod8$, and there aren't any squares congruent to 7 modulo 8.

Comment: And if $n\ge2$ then $2^n+15\equiv3\pmod 4$ and there aren't any squares congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.